# How to override android back button to add functionality

Tags: android

I want to override the android back button, I found code to do that,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

But now when I do this, the back button doesn't work,

how can I make a function call in this function such as to cancel a network request. amd then still let the default behaviour take place?

I am curerntly doing this in the onStop() Activity method

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Network.cancelRequests(ConnectingActivity.this);
}
```

However I don't think this is being called immediately when the user presses the back button as the response from the network request is still processed.

Comment: use this method instead `@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }` So if you want to perform the normal behavior, just return false under the if condition. Hope it will help you.

Comment: When you override the method. Don't forget to call super.onBackPressed()

Comment: have you tried calling `Network.cancelRequests(ConnectingActivity.this);` inside your `OnCreate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it in the following manner:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //your method call
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: On my screen it says HPTerm was faster

Comment: Perhaps I misread and was 12 sec faster. The only important thing is that your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm showing 8 seconds faster, but HpTerm has the right idea. Your problem is solved.

Comment: @Zapnologica you can validate TronicZomB as the fastest answer. I am not in a reputation race, the thing is to help others solve their problem. Moreover, to me, TronicZomB was a few secs faster.

Answer (score 2):

Most common mistake is to forget to call `super`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //your custom code here        
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Network.cancelRequests(ConnectingActivity.this);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

super.onBackPressed(); 
Network.cancelRequests(ConnectingActivity.this);

finish();

}